# Eureka error: No instances found after removing previously used service instance from the search

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, microservices, netflix-eureka

I have a sales-order-service which makes call to item-service, I am using resttemplate to make the call and the url is `http://item-service/item?name=` but i am getting the following error:

```
2023-09-23 18:47:31 2023-09-23 13:17:31.244  WARN 1 --- [io-9003-exec-10] .c.RetryAwareServiceInstanceListSupplier : No instances found after removing previously used service instance from the search ([EurekaServiceInstance@46d0eb66 instance = InstanceInfo [instanceId = 8425295e5cad:item-service:9001, appName = ITEM-SERVICE, hostName = localhost, status = UP, ipAddr = 172.18.0.5, port = 9001, securePort = 443, dataCenterInfo = com.netflix.appinfo.MyDataCenterInfo@258b098e]). Returning all found instances.
2023-09-23 18:47:31 2023-09-23 13:17:31.259 ERROR 1 --- [io-9003-exec-10] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://item-service/item": Connection refused; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused] with root cause
2023-09-23 18:47:31 
2023-09-23 18:47:31 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2023-09-23 18:47:31     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
2023-09-23 18:47:31     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579) ~[na:na]
2023-09-23 18:47:31     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568) ~[na:na]
2023-09-23 18:47:31     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:593) ~[na:na]
2023-09-23 18:47:31     at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
2023-09-23 18:47:31     at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:583) ~[na:na]
2023-09-23 18:47:31     at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:183) ~[na:na]
2023-09-23 18:47:31     at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:533) ~[na:na]
2023-09-23 18:47:31     at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:638) ~[na:na]
2023-09-23 18:47:31     at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:281) ~[na:na]
2023-09-23 18:47:31     at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:386) ~[na:na]
2023-09-23 18:47:31     at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:408) ~[na:na]
2023-09-23 18:47:31     at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1309) ~[na:na]
2023-09-23 18:47:31     at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1242) ~[na:na]
2023-09-23 18:47:31     at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1128) ~[na:na]
```

FYI I am only getting this error when running services on docker, but when i am running them without it this error does not occur. sales order and item service instances both are registered with eureka

I have tried changing the name of docker container as it was same as the application name to which i am making the call thinking it might be causing some conflict but that also didn't work.